# Use many terminal tabs to install using sudo command

Tags: sudo, lock

So there were several questions regarding how to run several terminal windows to install something with the command `sudo` -

Essentially what bothers me is the fact that I have to type the following two commands every time to unlock the process.

`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

This in my understanding is not an issue to the computer because I have checked every time there is no process to kill.

I have added something - to let several `sudo` commands to be operate - to a hidden file and `source`-d, after reading one advise but to no avail.

Comment: The command `sudo` has nothing to do with installing software on the computer, and it does not use the lock files `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock`. All `sudo` does is run a program under a different user account, usually the superuser's account. You may be confusing it with `dpkg` or one of the front-ends to `dpkg` such as `apt`, or `apt-get`, or `aptitude`. The confusion may arise from that `dpkg`, `apt` and friends are sometimes run with `sudo`, for example `sudo apt`.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "every time having to unlock the process"? What process is locked? Also, what did you add to what hidden file and what are you sourcing it for?

Comment: having to remove the two files - i thought something was locked.. the second part i think was something related to `visudo`, but I didnt write it down. have to look it up.

Answer (score 8):

Only one apt command can run at a time, thats why the lock-file exists. You risk messing up the apt database or installing conflicting packages if you "force" two or more apt commands to run side by side by deleting the lock-file .. Don't do it !!

Comment: oh man. I already did so many times.

Comment: @HSL you should rarely need to remove a lock file; if you need to do this regularly then this means that an issue exists elsewhere. Resolve _that_ issue and you won't need to remove lock files anymore. Continue to remove them manually and you're bound to end up with a broken APT.